# How to find users by their facebook uid in python social auth?

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, python-social-auth

I have parsed the friends data from the graph api and now I have the "friends" data which include the id of the friends.Now I am looking for a way to find users by the id, to add the User objects to each other as friends.

I know how to find one user's uid.

```
user = User.objects.get(......)
user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').uid
```

But how do I find User object by the uid?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a Request on URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<UID>
```

{
   "id": "358204548",
   "first_name": "someName",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "someLastName",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "username": "john.doe"
}

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the User object, not the user info, right?
I can't find it in any documentation, so I am not sure what's the best way to do it. But I found that this is how social_core get the user object during the login proccess: https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/df861e886f6984f813c1f1c5c9a0acffbe719e0d/social_core/pipeline/social_auth.py#L19

So this works for me:

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
user = UserSocialAuth.get_social_auth('facebook', uid).user
```

Hope this helps